# How to extract text content in html with pre tag

Tags: python, json, regex, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract text from the following html code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"data":{"about":"Berusaha &amp; Berdoa","anonymous":false,"avatar_id":"3","badges":[{"name":"Facebook","status":false,"type":"facebook"},{"name":"G+","status":true,"type":"gplus"},{"name":"Apple","status":false,"type":"apple"},{"name":"Phone number","status":true,"type":"phone"},{"name":"Email","status":true,"type":"email"}],"created_at":"2016-12-20T19:54:13+07:00","email":"popofaiqoh@gmail.com","has_phone":true,"id":"62588306","images":[{"external_id":"aeed6ljcgac33-ID","height":1080,"id":"1692268028","url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image","width":1080,"big":{"height":168,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image;s=168x168","width":168},"medium":{"height":120,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image;s=120x120","width":120},"background":{"height":1080,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image;s=1080x1080","width":1080},"small":{"height":72,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image;s=72x72","width":72}},{"external_id":"fbuhwnv63sni3-ID","height":0,"id":"1326400769","url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image","width":0,"big":{"height":168,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image;s=168x168","width":168},"medium":{"height":120,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image;s=120x120","width":120},"background":{"height":1080,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image;s=1080x1080","width":1080},"small":{"height":72,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image;s=72x72","width":72}}],"is_banned":false,"is_business":false,"is_phone_visible":true,"lang":"en","locations":[{"city_id":"","district_id":"","lat":0,"lon":0,"region_id":"","subregion_id":""}],"name":"Popy property Bali","name_provided":true,"phone":"+6281232483322","verification_status":"verified"},"metadata":{"update":null}}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I usually use BeautifulSoup to extract information from that html code, but for this case, it only has the pre tag so I have difficulties. I came up with idea to use regex to extract the text,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from urllib.request import urlopen as req 
import re


url = 'https://www.olx.co.id/api/users/62588306'

client = req(url)
page = client.read()
client.close()

page_html = soup(page, 'html.parser').text


kontak = re.search(r'\+\d{13}|\+\d{14}', page_html)
email  = re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_\{?\"?\:?]+\@[a-z0-9\.]+([a-z][\.a-z])?', page_html)

regexEmail  = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_\{?\"?\:?]+\@[a-z0-9\.]+([a-z][\.a-z])?', re.MULTILINE)


getEmail = regexEmail.match(page_html)

print(getEmail)
print(page_html)
```

(the html code above is from the "https://www.olx.co.id/api/users/62588306")

I just want to extract the email and the phone number, but the re.match() doesn't return any value, andnthe re.search() return the output

```
<re.Match object; span=(365, 394), match='"email":"popofaiqoh@gmail.com'>
```

Is there any way to just extract the email `popofaiqoh@gmail.com` ?

or should I use another code instead of regex?

Comment: Looks like JSON data to me. So, use a JSON parser.

Comment: Also, it looks like your regex search worked. You are looking at the string representation of the match object.

Answer (score 0):

First, use beautifulsoup to get the contents of `pre` tag, which is in JSON format, then parse it with Python's JSON library as follows:

```
import json
parsed_json = json.loads(pre_html) # contents of <pre>
print(parsed_json["data"]["email"])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to just extract the email `popofaiqoh@gmail.com`. You can try below code to get the `popofaiqoh@gmail.com`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

html="""<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"data":{"about":"Berusaha &amp; Berdoa","anonymous":false,"avatar_id":"3","badges":[{"name":"Facebook","status":false,"type":"facebook"},{"name":"G+","status":true,"type":"gplus"},{"name":"Apple","status":false,"type":"apple"},{"name":"Phone number","status":true,"type":"phone"},{"name":"Email","status":true,"type":"email"}],"created_at":"2016-12-20T19:54:13+07:00","email":"popofaiqoh@gmail.com","has_phone":true,"id":"62588306","images":[{"external_id":"aeed6ljcgac33-ID","height":1080,"id":"1692268028","url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image","width":1080,"big":{"height":168,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image;s=168x168","width":168},"medium":{"height":120,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image;s=120x120","width":120},"background":{"height":1080,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image;s=1080x1080","width":1080},"small":{"height":72,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/aeed6ljcgac33-ID/image;s=72x72","width":72}},{"external_id":"fbuhwnv63sni3-ID","height":0,"id":"1326400769","url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image","width":0,"big":{"height":168,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image;s=168x168","width":168},"medium":{"height":120,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image;s=120x120","width":120},"background":{"height":1080,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image;s=1080x1080","width":1080},"small":{"height":72,"url":"https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/fbuhwnv63sni3-ID/image;s=72x72","width":72}}],"is_banned":false,"is_business":false,"is_phone_visible":true,"lang":"en","locations":[{"city_id":"","district_id":"","lat":0,"lon":0,"region_id":"","subregion_id":""}],"name":"Popy property Bali","name_provided":true,"phone":"+6281232483322","verification_status":"verified"},"metadata":{"update":null}}</pre>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.text)

output = ""
for i in data['data']['email']:
    output += i
    
print(output)
```

Output: `popofaiqoh@gmail.com`